# Label - Object reference not set to an instance of an object C#

Tags: c#, winforms

On Windows 7 when running my program i get an error saying "Object reference is not set to an object".

On Windows 8.1 it runs perfectly fine.
I have narrowed it down to a single line causing this:

```
label14.Text = process["UserName"].ToString();
```

If i remove this line, it wont give any errors in Windows 7. I can also just do a `label14.Text = "Dummytext";` and it works.

Maybe its something to do with the foreach statement but its working just fine with the other variables and the username is working on Windows 8.1.

Any tips?

```
foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
{
    //print system info 

    process.Get();
    label6.Text = process["Manufacturer"].ToString() + " " + process["Model"].ToString();
    double Ram_Bytes = (Convert.ToDouble(process["TotalPhysicalMemory"]));
    label14.Text = process["UserName"].ToString();
    label12.Text = "" + (Math.Round(Ram_Bytes / 1073741824, 2)) + " GB";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It seems process["UserName"] int Windows 8.1 is not null but in Windows 7 its null. You can avoid the error by checking process["UserName"]  == null . But you have to check what else you can use instead of process["UserName"]  where it is missing

Comment: Add `if(process.ContainsKey("xyz"))` before using this entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to check either `prcess["UserName"]` is `null` or not. Then typecast it to `string`

```
if (prcess["UserName"] != null)
{
    label14.Text = process["UserName"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Didnt know that, didnt expect it to be null. Marked as answer, thank you :)